Trying to Prove set Identities
i am trying to prove or disprove the following set identity:
A̅ ∩ B̅ ∩ C = (A ⊕ C) ∩ (B ⊕ C)
What I've done so far is deciding to start from the right hand side and rewriting it as follows:
((A - C) ∪ (C - A)) ∩ ((B - C) ∪ (C - B))
((A ∩ C̅) ∪ (C ∩ A̅)) ∩ ((B ∩ C̅) ∪ (C ∩ B̅))
Not really sure where to go from here; I've tried using distributive law in reverse but that got me nowhere

Are those marks above some of those sets?  And what is $\oplus$?

@Randall Overlines on sets are another way of notating the set complement.  Oplus is another way of notating the symmetric difference of sets.  If you prefer, this can be written $A^c\cap B^c\cap C = (A\Delta C)\cap (B\Delta C)$

I know.  I was seeking clarity from OP.  Those overlines aren't very clear.  (Mathjax would, of course, fix this.)

Notice that the LHS is a subset of $C$.  Must it be true that an element of the RHS also be an element of $C$?  Or can you contrive an example where you find an element from outside of $C$ that is an element of the RHS?

 Even more explicitly, try letting $C=\emptyset$

$~$

 Let $A=B=\{1\}$ and $C=\emptyset$ (and the universal set being anything that includes $1$)

